# C# ThreadPool, почему не работает .ToArray()/

Tags: c#, массивы, многопоточность, list

Добрый вечер, не хочет работать `ToArray()`, да и вообще ни как не могу использовать результаты выполнения функции, которую я выполняю в пуле потоков.
В дебагере видно, что массив `globalOrder` содержит элементы, но он их не отдает, ни с помощью `.ToArray()`, ни перечислением всех объектов, итоговый массив `orders` просто остается пустым. В чем причина, может кто сталкивался?

p.s. до того, как я поместил её в ThreadPool все работало.

Фрагмент кода:

```
          ProgressbarModal bar1 = new ProgressbarModal();

          var timeStart = DateTime.Now;
          List<Order> globalOrder = new List<Order>();

          if (obj == null)
          {
          ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(test.GetOrders, globalOrder);
          }
          else if (obj is DateTime)
          {
          var param = new Tuple<DateTime, List<Order>>((DateTime)obj, globalOrder);
          ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(test.GetOrders1, param);
          }
          else if (obj is DateTime[])
          {
          var param = new Tuple<DateTime[], List<Order>>((DateTime[])obj, globalOrder);
          ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(test.GetOrders2, param);
          }
          else if(obj is Int32)
          {
          var param = new Tuple<Int32, List<Order>>((Int32)obj, globalOrder);
          ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(test.GetOrders3, param);
          }
          else
          {
          return;
          }

          bar1.ShowDialog();
          // Вот тут проблема, на точке останова, я вижу, что globalOrder
          // содержит 3000+ объектов, но массив orders так и остается пустой
          Order[] orders = globalOrder.ToArray();

          ProgressbarModal bar = new ProgressbarModal();

          ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(OrdersWorker.Insert, orders);
          bar.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: globalOrder точно заполнен?

Comment: Попробуй заюзать потокобезопасную колекцию для globalOrder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` говорит о том, что метод должен быть выполнен в потоке пула. После этого вызова программа продолжает выполняться дальше. Это значит, что когда вы обращаетесь к списку `globalOrder`, он еще не успел заполниться. Вам нужно переосмыслить то, что вы делаете, и, возможно, дожидаться окончания работы функций `GetOrders`.

К тому же стоит использовать потокобезопасную коллекцию (например, `ConcurrentBag<T>`), иначе при записи из одного потока и при чтении из другого потока возможны ошибки и/или получение неконсистентных данных. В этом не будет необходимости в случае, если вы будете дожидаться окончания работы потока.

Comment: в данном контексте, код продолжается, только после выполнения GetOrders. В этом я уверен :) Сейчас попробую потокобезопасную коллекцию использовать.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, потокобезопасные коллекции помогли, но все же не понятно, почему массив не заполнялся значениями, при том, что 
 тот массив, которые заполнялся в пуле, был не пустым?

Comment: @Kellso Особенность многопоточной работы - в том, что изменения, вносимые одним потоком, видны другим потокам не сразу.

Comment: @Kellso при правильных способах передачи данных это не проблема, поскольку примитив который выполняет синхронизацию обычно одновременно является и барьером памяти (memory fence). А вот вы что-то накрутили...

Comment: @Kellso точнее сказать не могу - надо видеть на какой такой магии у вас работает `ProgressbarModal`, скорее всего ошибка в нем.